# Do function calls as another functions parameters follow any defined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 is there any defined behaviour regarding the following? (i.e. does a = 1, 2 or is undefined)

```
void somefunc(int a, int b) {
  std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
}

int i = 0;
somefunc(++i, ++i)
```

Or should I write:

```
int i = 0;
int a = ++i;
int b = ++i;
somefunc(a, b);
```

The reason I ask, is I'm parsing a file for options and in one circumstance I'd like to create a keyvalue pair. And have functions similar to the following:

```
std::string create_key(std::string &source, size_t &size, int &index) {
  std:: string key = "";
  while(index < size) {
    // parse the string to create the key
    ++index
  }
  return key;
}

// Value is an base class for a template class. Allowing me to store values 
// of different data types inside a container.
Value* create_value(std::string &source, size_t &size, int &index) {
  Value* value = nullptr;
  while(index < size) {
    // determine type and assign it to value
    ++index;
  }
  return value;
}

std::map<std::string, Value*> create_object(std::string &source, size_t &size, int &index) {
  std::map<std::string, Value*> object;
  while(index < size) {
    // the line I think produces the same issue as my original example
    object.insert(std::pair<std::string, Value*>(create_key(source, size, index), create_value(source, size, index)));
    ++index;
  }
}
```

Comment: The order of evaluation on arguments is unspecified.

Comment: @ildjarn apologies, i meant int a = ++i; etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because you are modifying a variable in a manner which is not sequenced with respect to another modification of the same variable. Note that the comma is not a comma operator, which would introduce sequencing and prevent UB; it just separates the function arguments.

You cannot even do

```
somefunc(i, ++i)
```

without causing undefined behaviour. Modify the variable and then call the function (or vice versa if it's what you want) separately.

Comment: Minor detail: C++11 changes the phrasing, so "sequence point" is no longer used, though the same basic idea still applies.

Comment: @Seth : "Sequenced before" and "sequenced after".

Comment: @ildjarn: Or, in a case like this, "not sequenced" or "X is not sequenced with respect to Y".

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yeah, I think so anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which function arguments are evaluated is unspecified. `C++11 5.2.2.Function call para/4` states:

> When a function is called, each parameter shall be initialized with its corresponding
>   argument [Note: such initializations are **indeterminately sequenced** with respect to each other].

You should use:

```
somefunc (i+1, i+2); i += 2;
```

and stop worrying about such things.

This will work fine unless you're able to access `i` from elsewhere, in which case you have even *more* problems that should be fixed.